# How to create plots dynamically in grid.arrange in R?

Tags: r, dynamic, plot, ggplot2, r-grid

I have a function `get.single.plot`, which takes one character argument and returns a `ggplot2` plot object. I would like to build a `grid.arrange` object with `n` plots on it, where the `n` is the size of vector of (mentioned) character arguments.

E.g., I woould like something like this to work:

```
character.argument.vector <- c("12", "1", "2")
grid.arrange(unlist(lapply(character.argument.vector, function(n) get.single.plot(n))),
         ncol = 1)
```

Such thing does not work - I receive the following information:

```
Error in arrangeGrob(..., as.table = as.table, clip = clip, main = main,  : 
input must be grobs!
```

How should I do it?

Comment: `do.call(grid.arrange, c(lapply(), ncol=1))`

Comment: Thank you, @baptiste ! It is not the first time you helped me, I really appreciate your contribution to the community!

Comment: @Marciszka, that's probably because he is the author of `gridExtra` package...

Comment: does this only work work ggplots? I am using the standard plot() and using the same syntax that baptiste gives, and I get the same error as OP

Comment: @baptiste, please add your comment as a an answer.

Answer (score 2):

With gridExtra v>=2.0 you can simply pass a list of grobs (or plots) to grid.arrange,

```
grid.arrange(grobs = lapply(...), ncol=1)
```