# ggplots stored in plot list to respect variable values at time of plot generation within for loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, eval

I have an elaborate plot routine that generates box plots with additional layers of scatter and adds them to a plot list.

The routine generates correct plots if they are created during the for loop directly via `print(current_plot_complete)`.

However, if they are added to a plot list during the for loop which is printed only at the end, then the plots are incorrect: the final indices are used to generate *all* plots (instead of the current index at the time the plot is generated). 
This seems to be default `ggplot2` behavior and I am looking for a solution to circumvent it in the current use case.

The issue seems to be within `y = eval(parse(text=(paste0(COL_i))))` where the global environment is used (and thus the final index value) instead of the current values at the time of loop execution.

I tried various approaches to make [eval()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) use the correct variable values, e.g. `local(…)` or specifying the environment – but without success.

A very simplified MWE is provided below.

[image]

### MWE

The original routine is much more elaborate than this MWE such that the `for` loop can not be replaced easily with members of the `apply` family.

```
# create some random data
data_temp <- data.frame(
"a" = sample(x = 1:100, size  = 50),
"b" = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 45, sd = 1),
"c" = sample(x = 20:70, size  = 50), 
"d" = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 40, sd = 15),
"e" = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 50, sd = 10),
"f" = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 45, sd = 1),
"g" = sample(x = 20:70, size  = 50)
)
COLs_current <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e") # define COLs of data to include in box plots
choice_COLs <- c("a", "d")      # define COLs of data to add scatter to

plot_list <- list(NA)
plot_index <- 1

for (COL_i in choice_COLs) {

  COL_i_index <- which(COL_i == COLs_current)

  # Generate "basis boxplot" (to plot scatterplot on top)
  boxplot_scores <- data_temp %>% 
    gather(COL, score, all_of(COLs_current)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = COL, y = score)) +
    geom_boxplot() 

  # Get relevant data of COL_i for scattering: data of 4th quartile
  quartile_values <- quantile(data_temp[[COL_i]])
  threshold <- quartile_values["75%"]           # threshold = 3. quartile value
  data_temp_filtered <- data_temp %>%
    filter(data_temp[[COL_i]] > threshold) %>%  # filter the data of the 4th quartile
    dplyr::select(COLs_current)                 

  # Create layer of scatter for 4th quartile of COL_i
  scatter_COL_i <- geom_point(data=data_temp_filtered, mapping = aes(x = COL_i_index, y = eval(parse(text=(paste0(COL_i))))), color= "orange")

  # add geom objects to create final plot for COL_i
  current_plot_complete <- boxplot_scores + scatter_COL_i 

  print(current_plot_complete)

  plot_list[[plot_index]] <- current_plot_complete 
  plot_index <- plot_index + 1
}

plot_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose this solution which doesn't tell you why it doesn't work like you do :

```
l <- lapply(choice_COLs, temporary_function)

temporary_function <- function(COL_i){
    COL_i_index <- which(COL_i == COLs_current)

    # Generate "basis boxplot" (to plot scatterplot on top)
    boxplot_scores <- data_temp %>% 
        gather(COL, score, all_of(COLs_current)) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = COL, y = score)) +
        geom_boxplot() 

    # Get relevant data of COL_i for scattering: data of 4th quartile
    quartile_values <- quantile(data_temp[[COL_i]])
    threshold <- quartile_values["75%"]           # threshold = 3. quartile value
    data_temp_filtered <- data_temp %>%
        filter(data_temp[[COL_i]] > threshold) %>%  # filter the data of the 4th quartile
        dplyr::select(COLs_current)                 

    # Create layer of scatter for 4th quartile of COL_i
    scatter <- geom_point(data=data_temp_filtered,
                          mapping = aes(x = COL_i_index,
                                        y = eval(parse(text=(paste0(COL_i))))),
                          color= "orange")

    # add geom objects to create final plot for COL_i
    current_plot_complete <-  boxplot_scores + scatter

    return(current_plot_complete)
    }
```

When you use `lapply` you don't have such a problem.
It is inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993704/storing-ggplot-objects-in-a-list-from-within-loop-in-r)

Comment: thanks a lot for your fully functioning solution using `lapply(...)`. Though not expected at first I was able to work around my elaborate version to confirm with your prosed solution – which works well!

Comment: Arranging the plots stored in the list `l` in a joint plot requires subsetting `l`, i.e. `ggpubr::ggarrange(l[[1]], l[[2]])`. Else running `ggpubr::ggarrange(l)` would throw the following error `In as_grob.default(plot) : Cannot convert object of class list into a grob.`

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `ggplot` uses lazy evaluation.  When the `list` is rendered, the loop index has its final value, and that is the one used to render all the plots in the list.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235825/for-loop-only-adds-the-final-ggplot-layer) is relevant.

Comment: As an aside, the complexity of your plotting process suggests that your data might not be tidy in the context of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Indeed, the "issue" is a result of `ggplot`'s default behavior, as also noted above. I tried to convince `ggplot` to store or at least refer to the correct data by adding the `data` argument to `geom_point(data=data_temp_filtered,...` as proposed in the post you refer to, but it did not help.