# how to create multiple plots using for loop

Tags: r

I would like to create multiple plots using for loop setup. However my code does not work. Could anyone give me some guidance on this?

```
for i in 1:4 {
paste0("p_carb_",i) <- ggplot(mtcars%>% filter(carb==4), aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = disp)) 
+  geom_point()
}
```

Comment: "Does not work" isn't very precise, but I suspect you are a victim of [lazy evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation).  The solution is simple: use one of the `apply` family of functions (which force evaluation) rather than a `for` loop, which does not.  More detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799886/r-assigning-ggplot-objects-to-list-in-loop).  Also, `paste0("p_carb_",i)` creates a character string, which is not valid as the target of an assignment.

Comment: Is it a way to make `paste0("p_carb_",i)` a usable target to store the plots?

Comment: Objects are usually stored in lists.  So initialize a list prior to a loop, e.g. plotlist <- list().  Then inside the loop set plotlist(i) = ggplot...  But agree with Limey, better to use `lapply`.  Moreover, the ggplot function on the left hand side contains no `i` terms, so all iterations will return the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
ggs <- lapply(sort(unique(mtcars$carb)), function(crb) {
  ggplot(filter(mtcars, carb == crb), aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = disp)) +
    geom_point()
})
```

This produces six plots, which when the first two are viewed side-by-side (calling `ggs[[1]]` and then `ggs[[2]]`), we see

[image]

An alternative might be to facet the data, as in

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = disp)) +
  facet_wrap(~ carb) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

But the literal translation of your `paste(..) <- ...` code into something syntactically correct, we'd use an *anti-pattern* in R: `assign`:

```r
for (crb in sort(unique(mtcars$carb))) {
  gg <- ggplot(filter(mtcars, carb == crb), aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = disp)) +
    geom_point()
  assign(paste0("carb_", crb), gg)
}
```

Again, this is not the preferred/best-practices way of doing things. It is generally considered much better to keep like-things in a `list` for uniform/consistent processing of them.

---

Multiple IDs ... two ways:

1. Nested `lapply`:

   ```r
   carbs <- sort(unique(mtcars$carb))
   ggs <- lapply(carbs, function(crb) {
     gears <- subset(mtcars, carb == crb)$gear
     lapply(gears, function(gr) {
       ggplot(dplyr::filter(mtcars, carb == crb, gear == gr), aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = disp)) +
         geom_point()
     })
   })
   ```

   Where `ggs[[1]]` is a list of lists. `ggs[[1]][[1]]` will be one plot.
2. `split` list, one-deep:

   ```r
   carbsgears <- split(mtcars, mtcars[,c("carb", "gear")], drop = TRUE)
   ggs <- lapply(carbsgears, function(dat) {
     ggplot(dat, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = disp)) + geom_point()
   })
   ```

   Here, `ggs` is a `list` only one-deep. The names are just concatenated strings of the two fields, so since we have `mtcars$carb` with values `c(1,2,3,4,6,8)` and `mtcars$gear` with values `c(3,4,5)`, removing combinations without data we have names:

   ```r
   names(ggs)
   #  [1] "1.3" "2.3" "3.3" "4.3" "1.4" "2.4" "4.4" "2.5" "4.5" "6.5" "8.5"
   ```

   where `"1.3"` is `carb == 1` and `gear == 3`. When column names have dots in them, this might become ambiguous.

Comment: Your answer opens a whole new world to me :D

Comment: What if we have more complicate for loop setup, for example we have two part need to be loop  `for (i in ID) {  for (a in ID2) { ... ` , how can we set it up using `lapply`? I can't not think of a real sample data. Hopefully I explain it right.

Comment: Perhaps stick with faceting (again): `ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = disp)) + facet_grid(vs ~ carb) + geom_point()` (where you might instead choose `facet_grid(ID ~ ID2)`).

Comment: You can also nest calls to `lapply`.  That would handle OP's use case above.  The choice between many separate plots and a single faceted plot is multi-dimensional.  There is no absolute answer.  The better option will change on a case-by-case basis and will depend on the data, the message you want to convey, the audience ... and personal preference.

Comment: Thanks @Limey, well said.

Comment: @Limey Is it possible to give an example with  nest calls to lapply?

Comment: Yes.  I will do so.  But not until tomorrow.

Comment: @Limey Thanks. Looking forward :D

Comment: Not to steal your thunder @Limey, but ... Stataq, see my edit, particularly with the `split` option.

Comment: @r2evans: I'm always happy when someone volunteers to do my work for me.  Especially when it's someone as knowledgeable as yourself.

Comment: @Stataq, does that edit make sense?

Comment: @r2evans It is wonderful! Learned a lot from your answer. :D